# Difference in line-height fixable on zoomed view?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I have DIVs and a P overlayed with effective same line content.

In normal 100% zoom its rendered correct with no difference, but on Browser-Zoom 150% or Windows-Monitor-Zoom 150% there is a difference in the P-Tag.

All lines in P-tag are NOT rendered in the upscaled line-height. For example: one line should be 26px height. 14 sample lines should make 14 x 26px = 364px in height together, but its only 360.89px in zoomed mode.

The DIVs do zoom correct to 364px but the Ps only to 360.89px. Where does the difference come from and is there a way to fix it?

It does only happen in google chrome, not in firefox and not in edge.

Example code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OrBqKN

```css
#behind {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

#behind div {
  height: 26px;
}

#behind, #front {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#front p {
    color: red;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="behind">
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
  <div>test line</div>
  <div>next</div>
</div>
<div id="front"><p>test line
next
test line
next
test line
next
test line
next
test line
next
test line
next
test line
next</p>
</div>
```

[image: sample screenshots]

Comment: most likely some wired rounding error, does it still happen if you use a unit-less line-height ? `line-height: 1.3` ?

Comment: @Dirk: I can reproduce the issue also with unit-less lin-height. Sample issue: font-size: 20px; line-height: 1.5; (should result 30px) x 5 on 150% should be 150px, but are only 148.89px.

Comment: if you remove the `height` from `#behind div` the difference is gone, but its smaller in height in both cases. im still thinking this all is some float problem when multiplying and adding values in the browser engine, but i have no prove of that

Comment: @Dirk: okey thanks that works. so both are smaller but equal. i added it first to my code because it should work with empty lines (empty divs) too. but i found a fix for the empty div: an invisible ::after-element